# Filter the numeric elements based on target value in Prolog

Tags: arrays, list, sorting, filter, prolog

```
public class Filter {

  public static List<Number> apply(List<Number> lst, Double target){

    return lst.stream()
            .mapToDouble( Number::doubleValue )
            .filter( elem -> elem > target )
            .boxed()
            .collect( Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new ));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

//    Integer[] nums = new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

      Double[] nums = new Double[] {2.1,3.2,4.3,5.4,6.5,7.6,8.7};

      System.out.println(Filter.apply( Arrays.asList(nums), 5.0 ) 
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: what you want from your code?

Comment: i want a numbers greater then given number like all number from double array greater then 5.0

Comment: or in short i want to convert this java apply method into PROLOG

Comment: Umar: thant's what your program is doing, it would return all upper values greater than 5.0

`[5.4, 6.5, 7.6, 8.7]`

Comment: Yes i need it in PROLOG language

Comment: Of interest: RosettaCode Filter - [Prolog](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Filter#Prolog)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
%---------------------------
% find all Xs greater than Y
%---------------------------
items_greater_than( []     , _ , []    ) .
items_greater_than( [X|Xs] , Y , [X|Zs ) :- X @>  Y, items_greater_than(Xs,Y,Zs).
items_greater_than( [X|Xs] , Y , Zs    ) :- X @=< Y, items_greater_than(Xs,Y,Zs).
```

Executing

```
items_greater_than( [2.1, 3.2, 4.3, 5.4, 6.5, 7.6, 8.7], 5.0, R ).
```

should yield

```
R = [ 5.4, 6.5, 7.6, 8.7 ]
```

Comment: s(X) for the predicate name ! thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Java `filter` is [include/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=include/3) from library([apply](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=apply)), while library([yall](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall)) gives us anonymous predicates, similar to `arrow functions`:

```
items_greater_than(Items,Value,ItemsGreater) :-
  include({Value}/[I]>>(I>Value),Items,ItemsGreater).
```

If your Prolog is missing either of the above libraries, this could work:

```
items_greater_than(Items,Value,ItemsGreater) :-
  findall(I,(member(I,Items),I>Value),ItemsGreater).
```

Remember that in Prolog we don't have functions, but predicates.

*edit*

Thanks to the wise comment by @TA_intern, here is a solution that doesn't require library(yall):

```
items_greater_than(Items,Value,ItemsGreater) :-
  include(<(Value),Items,ItemsGreater).
```

Since library(apply) appends lists items to the end of arguments of the predicate, we use the [(<)/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3C)/2) predicate instead of [(>)/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3E)/2).

Comment: I don't want to downvote but the lambda is really unnecessary. You could have called this directly, `include(<(5.0), ...)` or used compare/3, like `include(compare(<, 5.0), ...)`

Comment: @TA_intern: you're true, my bad. Will amend my answer.

Comment: @TA_intern: done, but I think there is some didactic value in simple, practical examples of lambda libraries usage. So I will leave the library(yall) based solution available.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SWI-Prolog, you would use include/3, like this:

```
?- include(<(5.0), [2.1,3.2,4.3,5.4,6.5,7.6,8.7], R).
R = [5.4, 6.5, 7.6, 8.7].
```

This does exactly the same as the Java code: it takes a list, applies a predicate to each element, and collects only the elements for which the predicate succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that split/3 and merge/3 are ''help-predicates'' :

```
split([X], [], [X]).

split([H1, H2 | List], [H1 | ListA], [H2 | Result]) :-
    split(List, ListA, Result).

merge([], L, L).
merge(L, [], L).

merge([H1 | List], [H2 | ListA], [H1 | Result]) :-
    H1 < H2,
    !,
    merge(List, [H2 | ListA], Result).

merge(List, [H2 | ListA], [H2 | Result]) :-
    merge(List, ListA, Result).


merge_sort([], []).
merge_sort([A], [A]).

merge_sort(List, SList):-
  split(List, List1, List2),
  merge_sort(List1, SList1),
  merge_sort(List2, SList2),
  merge(SList1, SList2, SList).
```

If you query, you should get this:

```
?- split([2, 5, 7, 4, 3, 1, 9, 8, 6], ListA, ListB).
ListA = [2, 7, 3, 9],
ListB = [5, 4, 1, 8, 6] .

?- merge([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8], MergedList).
MergedList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] .

?- merge_sort([2, 5, 7, 4, 3, 1, 9, 8, 6], Result).
Result= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].
```

Comment: #Hyakkimaru I don,t need sorting i need to get all upper number from target number from array in PROLOG